# increment number in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, counter

I am using counter in Azure Devops Pipeline to increment version number:

```
variables:
  flag: PUBLISH
  version: 1.0
  ${{ if eq( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    ${{ if  contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'PUBLISH') }}:
      patch: $[ counter(variables['version'],1) ]
```

I then pass $(version).$(patch) as the parameters for the published artifact:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: './artifact/project.file.exe'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'organization/project'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: "file"
    packagePublishDescription: "file version $(version).$(patch)"
```

It is working well, but the problem is that the $(patch) increment even when the build fails. so sometimes I have a version jump of 2.

Is there a way for the counter uncount in case of pipe failure?

Another solution I was thinking about is getting the latest version from the Artifact and then increment that number by one, but how can I use a code (maybe rest api) to get the latest version?

I tried " GET [https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/Packages/{packaged}/versions?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://feeds.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/packaging/Feeds/%7BfeedId%7D/Packages/%7Bpackaged%7D/versions?api-version=6.0-preview.1) "
But I get back a reply that package has been moved..

Thank you.

Comment: I'd recomend you make pre-release branch where add prerelease counter or use variable of build number. Then your prerelease version will be like 1.x.x-pre1. Run builds and tests on that and merge in main branch only when build is stable.
Semiversioning and prerelease approach described here: https://semver.org/

Comment: Hi Amir, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for the counter uncount in case of pipe failure?

There is no way around this. Because the value of this thing is only affected by both the pipeline run and the prefix, nothing else can change it. With the prefix unchanged, this number keeps adding up as long as you run the pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter

> Another solution I was thinking about is getting the latest version
> from the Artifact and then increment that number by one, but how can I
> use a code (maybe rest api) to get the latest version?

This is the way to go. Very simple, only need to use two rest api:

**1，Use this API to list the feeds under the specific organization**

`https://feeds.dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_apis/packaging/feeds?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

**2, Use this API to list the packages under the specific feed, this can get the latest version of specific package**

`https://feeds.dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_apis/packaging/Feeds/<Feed ID(we can get this from the previous API)>/packages?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

[image]

Please notice that the above API doesn't have an official document, but I have tested it and it works fine. I can use them to get the latest version of package successfully.

The auth method is 'basic auth', and you just need to give the PAT to it.